# "The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint" error Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I'm trying to add a button and set the constraints programmatically, but I keep getting this error and can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I've looked at other questions on here but they haven't been too helpful in my case.

```
    btn.setTitle("mybtn", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    view.addSubview(btn)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .leftMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leftMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let right = NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .rightMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .rightMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    btn.addConstraints([left, right, top])
```

Comment: Where are you putting this code in?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When [adding constraints](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622513-addconstraints) to a view, "any views involved [in the constraint] must be either the receiving view itself, or a subview of the receiving view". You're adding the constraint to `btn`, so it doesn't understand what to make of the `view` referenced by the constraint, because it's neither `btn` nor a subview of `btn`. The error would be resolved if you added the constraints to `view`, instead of `btn`.

Or even better, as Khalid said, use `activate` instead, in which case you don't need to worry about where in the view hierarchy you are adding the constraint:

```
let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
btn.setTitle("mybtn", for: .normal)
btn.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
btn.backgroundColor = .lightGray
view.addSubview(btn)
btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    btn.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
    btn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Comment: Thank you. Been looking for this.

Answer (score 3):

Use activate constraint. as off iOS 9 you can use activate

```
 btn.setTitle("mybtn", for: .normal)
 btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
 btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

 btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 self.view.addSubview(btn)


let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .leftMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leftMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

let right = NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .rightMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .rightMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: btn, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

// here you have to call activate constraints everything will work     
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([left, right, top])
```

[example project](https://www.swiftyninja.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/constraints.zip)

Comment: That `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` method is actually just a shortcut bro. From Apple docs: *Activating or deactivating the constraint calls `addConstraint(_:)` and `removeConstraint(_:)` on the view that is the closest common ancestor of the items managed by this constraint.*

Comment: Sorry If I have been impolite

Comment: That's why I love so much the SO community… we let the code do the talking:-) KhalidAfridi, @Rob

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `left` and `right`constraints to the `view` instead of `btn`.